# Powershell: Setting values of a filtered array

Tags: arrays, powershell, csv

I want to read in a csv file, filter it based on the values of two of
the fields and set the value of another field. Here's a simple example
of what I'm trying to achieve:

c:\somefile.csv contents:

```
firstField,secondField,thirdField
1,2,"somevalue"
2,2,"avalue"
3,1,"somevalue"

#Import file into array
$csv = Import-Csv c:\somefile.csv

# Where secondField = 2 and thirdField = "someValue" set thirdField =
"anotherValue"
$csv | where {$_secondField -eq 2 -and $_.thirdField = "somevalue"} |
<set value of thirdField = "anotherValue">
```

How can I do this. As you can see, from the example about, I can read
in and filter the array. But I don't know how to then set the value of
the thirdField. I tried set-itemproperty but got the error: "The
WriteObject and WriteError methods cannot be called after the pipeline
has been closed".

Edit: I would also only like to change to value of the first 2 items (rows) returned.
Answered by me: I used Select -first 2.

Any advice on how to achive this would be appreciated.

Alan T

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I altered your code a little bit:

```
$csv | 
    Where-Object {$_.secondField -eq 2 -and $_.thirdField -eq 'somevalue'} |
    Foreach-Object { $_.thirdField = 'anotherValue' }
```

- `$_secondField` => `$_.secondField`
- `$_.thirdField = "somevalue"` should be `$_.thirdField -eq "somevalue"`
- `Foreach-Object` sets the third value. It processes only 1 record in this case, but basically it processes all the records that are piped in (just try to remove the `Where` part).
- it is 'safer' to use single quote instead of double quote because of unintended variable expansion.

Comment: Note to self: Make sure that the header line in the CSV has no trailing space ... that threw me off with my testing for the past few minutes here ...

Answer (score 2):

You've got the right idea.  Use `Where-Object` (aliased to Where) to filter the objects in the pipeline and then further down the pipeline use `Foreach-Object` (aliased to Foreach) to set the value like so:

```
$csv | where {$_secondField -eq 2 -and $_.thirdField -eq "somevalue"} | 
    foreach {$_.thirdField = "notherValue"}
```

Think of Where-Object as just a filter mechanism and Foreach-Object as the pipeline mechanism that allows you to apply arbitrary script to each pipeline object.